# How do I remain the image when I update edit form?

Tags: php

I can update image on my application but if I have to update same picture again and again when I click edit button on edit section...so I want to remain current image when I update edit section without any change for image.

I tried to put these codes below but it didn't work....

```
if(empty($image)){
        $selected_image = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id={$the_post_id}");
        $selected_image->execute(array($the_post_id));
        $selected_images = $selected_image->fetch();
    }
```

Does anyone give some advise or concern for my codes?
I really appreciate!
Thank you!

```
<!-- Edit -->
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit_post_id'])){
    $the_post_id = $_REQUEST['edit_post_id'];
    
    $posted = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id ");
    $posted->execute(array($the_post_id));
    $posted_p = $posted->fetch();
}
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['edit_post'])){
    
        $edit_posts = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET post_image=?, post_contents=? WHERE post_id ='{$the_post_id}' ");
        $edit_posts->execute(array(
            $image = date('YmdHis') . $_FILES['image']['name'],
            $_POST['post_contents']
            ));
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], './images/' . $image);
        
    if(empty($image)){
        $selected_image = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id={$the_post_id}");
        $selected_image->execute(array($the_post_id));
        $selected_images = $selected_image->fetch();
    }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
?>

<!-- Edit form -->
<div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
            <div class="well">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div>
                        <label for="summernote">Edit</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_contents" id="summernote" col="30" rows="10"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($posted_p['post_contents'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="post_image">Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="image"  >
                        <img width="100" src="./images/<?php echo $posted_p['post_image']; ?>" >
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-group">
                        <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="edit_post" value="Edit"></p>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should update your query so it sets `post_image` only if `$_FILES['image']` it exists

this should work:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['edit_post'])){
        $image = $_FILES['image'] ? date('YmdHis') . $_FILES['image']['name'] : "";

        $edit_posts = $db->prepare(
          "UPDATE posts SET post_contents=?". empty($image) ?: ", post_image=?" ."WHERE post_id ='{$the_post_id}' "
        );
        $params = array(
            $_POST['post_contents']
        );
        if (!empty($image)) {
          $params[] = $image;
        }
        $edit_posts->execute($params);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], './images/' . $image);

        if(empty($image)){
            $selected_image = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id={$the_post_id}");
            $selected_image->execute(array($the_post_id));
            $selected_images = $selected_image->fetch();
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Nao make sure `images` directory exists